# Multiple enumerations in complex sentence. Correct punctuation

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to understand how to correctly apply punctuations to complex sentences.

Sentence example:

> Learned activities A, B, C, D, E using tools F, G, H, I, J and documents K, L, M, N, O, P, R.

Having the sentence above, what punctuation should be applied to the words [activities, tools, documents] that go before enumerating words [A, B, C, D, E  ;  F, G, H, I, J  ;  K, L, M, N, O, P, R] ?

Comment: Your example is not a complete sentence.

Comment: Is it because of pattern A,B,C.. words ? Can punctuation change if you put various pattern words ?

Comment: You need a subject, as James K's answer points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use commas or nothing if not too confusing:

> I have learned activites A,B, and C using tools M,N and O and tools X,Y and Z.

You could put a comma after C and O

Probably rephrase:  If this was a real example, from a resume or similar and the activities, tools and documents were more than one letter long, the expression would be over-long and hard to follow.  You should probably use bulleted lists

> Activites I have learned:
>
> - A
> - B
> - C
>
> Tools used
>
> - E
> - F

Or some similar typographical device.